# How to avoid using multiple include or require in PHP?

Tags: php, wrapper

For example lets assume that i am using a library called available online called "alpha". This library has a file called Authenticate.php, which i need to include in every file to make use of the library.

For example:

```
for login.php
<?php
include 'Authenticate.php';
include 'Everything.php'; 
sac::forceAuthentication();
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Authentication Succeeded</h1>
</body></html>
?>

for logout.php  
<?php
include 'Authenticate.php';
include 'Everything.php';
sac::logout();
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Logout Successful</h1>
</body></html>
?>
```

As you can see i need to include Authenticate.php in all my files to use the functionalities of Authenticate.php

Is there a way i can avoid doing this, by including Authenticate.php in Everything.php file?

To avoid this i was thinking of the following possible solution, do let me know if this is valid way of doing this.

I am planning include following functions of Authenticate.php in Everything.php by doing the following

```
class Everything {

    public function Login(){
        include_once('Authenticate.php');
        sac::forceAuthentication();

    }
   public function logout(){
        include_once('Authenticate.php');
        sac::logout();
   }
 // Some other functions of everything.php
}
```

Note: Authenticate.php has many other functionalities which i don't need, I want to use just the selected functionalities and include in Everything.php

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is why [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and autoloaders exist, eg: [Composer's autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Comment: `auto_prepend_file` directive in your `php.ini` file perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `include` inside of a function is probably not a good idea. If it assigns variables that are supposed to be global, they will only be in the scope of that function, not global any more.

You can create a file that includes both `Authenticate.php` and `Everything.php`. Call it `AuthEverything.php`, and it would contain:

```
include_once('Authenticate.php');
include_once('Everything.php');
```

Then put `include_once('AuthEverything.php')` in your `login.php` and `logout.php`.

Comment: Thank you Barmer. Another question is, if i want to create a single package with these two Authenticate.php and Everything.php. Could you give any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by creating a package. Like for distributing on Github?

Comment: Lets say, I want to create a single class (AuthEverything.php) with the functionalities of both Authenticate.php and Everything.php to make a package. So that My colleagues can use this package and get all the functionalities of these two files. Do i make sense?

Comment: Sorry, packaging libraries isn't really my area of expertise. But I see lots of libraries that are spread over multiple files, and you access them with nested namespaces: `\Parent\Child\Classname`.